# Hibernate Duplicate Import Error when adding a new xml

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have been trying to fix this error. Every time I add the HistoryLog.hbm.xml I get the Duplicate error below.

```
Mar 11, 2016 4:51:54 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MappingsImpl addImport
INFO: HHH000071: Duplicate import: persistent.Account -> persistent.Account
Mar 11, 2016 4:51:54 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MappingsImpl addImport
INFO: HHH000071: Duplicate import: persistent.Account -> Account
```

But I can't find the reason why it keeps happening. I have posted the xmls involve below

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
          "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
          "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated by MyEclipse Hibernate Tools.                   -->
<hibernate-configuration>

<session-factory>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="connection.url">
        jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bank_system
    </property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">
        com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    </property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">12345</property>
    <property name="dialect">
        org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    </property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <mapping resource="Account.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping resource="User.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping resource="TransactionalLog.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping resource="RequestTransferLog.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping resource="HistoryLog.hbm.xml" />
</session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

HistoryLog.hbm.xml

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC  
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"  
 "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="persistent.HistoryLog" table="account_history_log">
   <id name="historyLogCounter" type="long" column="history_log_counter">
    <generator class="identity"></generator>
   </id>

    <property name="accountID" column="account_id" type="long"/>
    <property name="userId" column="user_id" type="long"/>
    <property name="officerID" column="officer_id" type="long"/>
    <property name="dateTime" column="date_time" type="java.util.Date"/>
    <property name="actionDone" column="action_done" type="string"/>
    <property name="remarks" column="remarks" type="string"/>

 </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Account.hbm.xml

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>  
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC  
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"  
 "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">  

<hibernate-mapping>  
 <class name="persistent.Account" table="account">  
   <id name="accountId" type="long" column="account_id">  
    <generator class="assigned"></generator>
   </id>  

    <property name="balance" column="balance" type="float"/>    
    <property name="userId" column="user_id" type="long"/>    

 </class>  

</hibernate-mapping>
```

EDIT: Added my find *.xml

```
./src/hibernate.cfg.xml
./src/User.hbm.xml
./src/Account.hbm.xml
./src/HistoryLog.hbm.xml
./src/TransactionalLog.hbm.xml
./src/RequestTransferLog.hbm.xml
./WebRoot/WEB-INF/web.xml
./WebRoot/WEB-INF/classes/hibernate.cfg.xml
./WebRoot/WEB-INF/classes/User.hbm.xml
./WebRoot/WEB-INF/classes/Account.hbm.xml
./WebRoot/WEB-INF/classes/HistoryLog.hbm.xml
./WebRoot/WEB-INF/classes/TransactionalLog.hbm.xml
./WebRoot/WEB-INF/classes/RequestTransferLog.hbm.xml
./.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml
```

Comment: Are you certain that there are not 2 copies of the file present in the same directory?

Comment: Can you check once at, It may help you: https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topic/org-hibernate-mappingexception-duplicate-import/

Comment: I have edited my post to include the find *.xml. and as you can see there is no duplicate files. Ill try to check the link Dhana, thanks